# What is the optimal way to perform many parallel web requests, while avoiding memory leaks and dangling sockets? (C#)

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

I need to perform many web requests in parallel (roughly 1000 per second). Some of these web requests will time out (the server won't respond), and I need to be able to handle this. Many requests will need to be routed through a proxy (and there are many different proxies that will need to be used).

Because of the need for proxies, one HttpClient cannot be reused (which is the conventional wisdom for performing multiple requests). The naive way of doing this, then, would be to start a bunch of threads, and in each one, instantiate a new HttpClient with its own handler, and perform the request. But that still leaves the issue of leaving many sockets open. So that's not really an option.

What I'm doing at the moment is this:

```
class GetRequest
    {
        private int timeout;
        private WebRequest req;
        private string url;
        private ManualResetEvent allDone;
        private string response;
        private IWebProxy proxy;

        public GetRequest(string url, int timeout = 3000, IWebProxy proxy = null)
        {
            this.url = url;
            this.timeout = timeout;
            this.response = "";
            this.proxy = proxy;
        }

        public string Get()
        {
            allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            req = WebRequest.Create(url);
            req.Proxy = proxy;
            req.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36";
            req.Timeout = this.timeout;

            req.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, req);
            allDone.WaitOne(timeout);
            Cleanup();
            return this.response;
        }
        private HttpWebResponse webresponse;
        private Stream streamResponse;
        private StreamReader streamRead;

        private void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {

            // End the operation
            webresponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
            streamResponse = webresponse.GetResponseStream();
            streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse);
            string responseString = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
            this.response = responseString;
            // Close the stream object
            streamResponse.Close();
            streamRead.Close();

            // Release the HttpWebResponse
            webresponse.Close();
            allDone.Set();
        }

        ~GetRequest()
        {
            Cleanup();
        }

        public void Cleanup()
        {
            try
            {
                streamResponse?.Close();
            } catch { }
            try
            {
                streamRead?.Close();
            }
            catch { }
            try
            {
                webresponse?.Close();
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

I can then start a bunch of threads and create new `GetRequest` objects, dispatch them, and then call `Cleanup()`.

Is this sufficient to avoid memory leaks and dangling sockets? Is there a *better* way of doing this?

(excuse the quality of this code, it's very much in the early development stage at the moment)

Comment: Are you writing a DDOS client?  But seriously, the better way would be to (if possible) allow more data to be returned from a single call so you don't have to waste so much bandwidth with the request overhead.

Comment: I think at 1000/second you may fairly quickly run out of sockets that aren't finished closing

Comment: @Louis Ingenthron not a DDOS client - each endpoint is different  - you could liken the behaviour of the program to being similar in nature to a web crawler/indexer, though some behaviour is different. It's part of some academic research I'm doing.

Comment: @Caius Jard possibly. My bigger concern is that, once all requests have finished (or timed out), I'd like to prevent there being and resources still locked up (or minimise them, at least).